# Azure - monitoring resources using REST APIs

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-monitoring

I am new to Azure and have been going through various tutorials. 
I am looking specifically at Azure Monitoring using REST APIs.

What I am trying to do is get the status of various resources like Virtual Networks, AD, Load Balancers etc on a custom dashboard using REST APIs.

I have found some list of REST APIs that allow monitoring here(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/)

But do they provide Resource health and Status.Also, do i have a create a new Service API Managament Resource(which is a paid resource) in the Azure Account for these APIs to run?.

Please let me know if you have any insights or reference materials on this

Answer (score -1):

I don't think rest API is good for monitoring. I will suggest use Azure Monitor service under that you can use Azure resource metrics, Activity logs and service health. based on these metrics and logs you can set alert and show live data on the dashboard.

We are using Microsoft OMS for live monitoring (visualization of data) and Email/SMS for notification.

1. List item

[image]

[Audit and receive notifications about important actions in your Azure subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitor-quick-audit-notify-action-in-subscription)

Comment: Definently the way to go with monitoring Azure. At least for starters. Then you can always decide if you want more.

Comment: @Pankaj Anyone with little online reading can know about management consoles, REST API is my requirement, so please let me know if you have used REST API for monitoring. Also your statement "I don't think rest API is good for monitoring" needs to be backed up with facts